# Getting reply message from Kafka

Tags: node.js, spring-cloud, spring-kafka

I am using Kafkajs producing the message to a spring boot application that implement as reply template

```
@KafkaListener(topics = KHQRTopic.GENERATE_KHQR, groupId = KafkaConfiguration.CONSUMER_GROUP)
@SendTo
public Message<?> onEventGenerateKHQR(ConsumerRecord<String, KHQRRequest> consumerRecord) {
        log.info("Received event {}", consumerRecord.value());
...
}
```

On my node.js I have get result from Kafka like this

```
export const getResult = async <T>(messageOption: MessageOption, data: any) => {
  const processID = new Date().getTime().toString()
  let payload: string | Buffer = ''
  
    if (messageOption.avroSchemaName) {
      payload = await registry.encode(
        getSchemaId(messageOption.avroSchemaName),
        data
      );
    } else {
      payload = JSON.stringify(data)
    }
    
  
    const replyTopic = messageOption.replyTopic ?? `${messageOption.sendTopic}.reply`
    console.log('wait result form', replyTopic)
    await producer.send({
      topic: messageOption.sendTopic,
      messages: [
        { key: processID, value: payload,
          headers: {
          'reply-topic': replyTopic
      } }],
      
    });

    return await getMessageResponse<T>(
      replyTopic,
      processID,
      messageOption.timer
    );
}
```

When sending message I got error on consumer at spring application

```
org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener failed
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.decorateException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2946) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2887) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2854) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.lambda$doInvokeRecordListener$57(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2772) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
    at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.lambda$observe$4(Observation.java:544) ~[micrometer-observation-1.11.5.jar:1.11.5]
    at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.observeWithContext(Observation.java:603) ~[micrometer-observation-1.11.5.jar:1.11.5]
    at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.observe(Observation.java:544) ~[micrometer-observation-1.11.5.jar:1.11.5]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2770) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2622) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2508) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2150) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeIfHaveRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1505) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1469) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1344) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1804) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: With no topic header, a defaultTopic is required
```

It seems like the headers is mismatch. What headers are accepted for the reply topic when using Replying template on spring?

What the payload of message should be to make communicate between these 2 application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/receiving-messages/annotation-send-to.html

> `@SendTo` (no properties): This is treated as `!{source.headers['kafka_replyTopic']}`

So, the header name containing a reply topic must be `kafka_replyTopic`, not what you have done so for with `'reply-topic': replyTopic` on your JS code.